# Redirect from folder-URL only to another URL (but allow subfolder-URLs)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect from

`http://example.com/folder`

to

`http://example.com/`

But still be able to access

`http://example.com/folder/subfolder`

without being redirected. So only the specific "folder"-URL should be redirected to root. Is that doable? Can't seem to exclude the subfolders.

Current code (that is redirecting folder/subfolder as well) is:

```
Redirect folder https://www.example.com/
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question to fix what you wrote. The first two URLs you wrote are identical ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the `Redirect` directive that matches any URI that starts with the given pattern. Here it will match any URI that starts with `/folder`.

You can use `RedirectMatch` for precise matching using regex:

```bash
RedirectMatch 302 ^/folder/$ https://www.example.com/
```

Or use `RewriteRule`:

```bash
RewriteRule ^/?folder/$ https://www.example.com/ [L,R=302,NC]
```

Note that I have kept leading `/` optional in `RewriteRule`. That makes this rule compatible with Apache server config where it should start with a `/` and .htaccess where leading `/` is not matches since `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: I think it often makes sense to elaborate over the different matching patterns required depending on where you implement a `RewriteRule`, in a central or in a distributed configuration file. _Or_ to implement the rule in a neutral form. At least that should be _mentioned_ ...

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. I have made `/` optional at the start and have written a note